# MS Access: Display two columns in combo-box

Tags: combobox, ms-access-2010

Embarrassingly simple question but I can't work it out or find the answer via google.

Got something like this with two colums

[image: contacts dropdown]

But when selected it only displays one column, making the information much harder to read/ understand.

[image: contact]

Tried changing properties in property sheet (such as column number) but to no apparent effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends to a certain extent on what you are doing, often something like this suits:

```
SELECT Id, Surname & ", " & Forename from Table
```

In other words, the bound column is a unique ID and the selection column includes both the surname and forename in a single column.

EDIT based on additional information:

```
SELECT [Contact].[CID], [Contact].[Csname] & ", " & [Contact].[Cfname] 
FROM [Contact] ORDER BY [CID], [Csname], [Cfname];
```

Comment: Thanks, but the SQL is already .... SELECT [Contact].[CID], [Contact].[Csname], [Contact].[Cfname] FROM [Contact] ORDER BY [CID], [Csname], [Cfname]; it is automatically expanding (when clicked upon) to include both columns (the ID column is hidden) - but unfortunately collapses otherwise. May just have to bundle first and last names into a single column!

Comment: That is what I was suggesting. The alternative is to include textboxes to write the columns out to, but concatenating surname with forename is usually a more pleasing solution.

Answer (score 2):

Since my first column is used to group items in the second it didn't look nice to just separate them using

```
SELECT ID, [Type] & ": " & [Title] AS BothValues
```

as suggested. With a lot of items the dropdown looks confusing [like in this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5W7ls.png).

I found out that Access seems to display the first **(technically) visible** column in the combobox after a selection has been made. Therefore I ended up using

```
SELECT ID, [Type] & ": " & [Title] AS BothValues, Type, Title
```

and setting the width of the second column to the smallest possible, de facto invisible value (0";0.007";1",1"). Don't forget to raise the column count (4). Now the [dropdown appears grouped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKgXv.png), but I still get both information after the selection.

Comment: Oh I love this solution. Worked great for me

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a visual workaround for this Access limitation, using a text box at the right of the combobox, and setting the textbox value equal to the third column of the combobox.

If the combobox is based on

```
SELECT [Contact].[CID], [Contact].[Csname], [Contact].[Cfname] 
FROM [Contact] ORDER BY [CID], [Csname], [Cfname];
```

Set column width equal to 0cm;5cm;6cm (or whatever you may need) and combobox width equal to the second column (5cm).
Then create a new text box at the right of the combobox, without any space in between, set its width equal to the third column (6cm) and set textbox controlsource equal to:

```
=[combobox_name].[Column](2)
```

Textbox will not be modifiable by the user since it is associated to a control source.