# Is there a R Shiny combo box like the MsAccess-display-two-columns-in-combo-box

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to create an selectinput to display multiple fields (variablename, sparklinehistogram, sparkinebox) from a datatable. The two fields sparklinehistogram and sparklinebox are just infofields about the distribution of the variablename.

In MsAccess such a possibility exists. ([MS Access: Display two columns in combo-box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762395/ms-access-display-two-columns-in-combo-box))

Can (and how can) this be done in R shiny?

I hope I find something like this:
[image]

Comment: You could do a datatable with sparkline, as [here](https://leonawicz.github.io/HtmlWidgetExamples/ex_dt_sparkline.html) or [here](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3318222/how-to-add-sparklines-to-r-tables.html).

Comment: Look at my answer to myself https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53188200/in-shiny-selectinput-to-have-value-et-label-with-vertical-align-and-spaces-not/53195361#53195361

Comment: The combination of my answer (many columns in select input) and Stéphane Laurent answer  (sparkline that I didn't know) will be a good solution :)