# MS Access: Linking 2 tables with calculated fields? (not merging)

Tags: ms-access

Let's say I have the following 2 tables (this is made up data served as example).

Table 1 contains employees info (Name and Departments).
Table 2 track late clock-in time daily.

My task is to fill in Table 2 and occasionally update Table 1.

Since each employee is identified by Name and Departments, I want to merge these 2 fields into one single column. Then in Table 2 select that as lookup.

**Important: I also want that any changes made to Table 1 (Name/Departments) is automatically reflected in Table 2.**

The issue is: I cannot created a Relationship involving a calculated field in Access.

Is there a better way? I'm new to Access so any help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

Example below:

**Table 1**

| EmployeeID | EmployeeName | Departments | NameAndDepartments (calculated from the other 2 fields) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ann | Sales | Ann from Sales |
| 2 | Bob | Marketing | Bob from Marketing |
| 3 | Charles | IT | Charles from IT |

**Table 2**

| Instance | NameAndDepartments (lookup field to Table 1 - dropdown menu) | Late clock-in | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ann from Sales | 15 minutes | 24-04-2023 |
| 2 | Charles from IT | 5 minutes | 24-04-2023 |

Comment: Table2 should NOT save name, only employee ID. Tables are link on key fields. Basic RDBMS principle.

Comment: Filling Table 2 using EmployeeID will be slower since I have to check the ID back and forth. Is there no other way?

Comment: What do you mean by 'check the ID back and forth' - check where and when? I won't even touch 'other way' with a 10-ft pole.

Comment: Say I need to fill Table2. I know "Ann from Sales" is late by 15 min, but I don't know their EmployeeID. To get the EmployeeID I need to open Table1 to find that their ID is "1". Only then I can fill Table2. It will take a lot of time if I have to check their EmployeeID each time.

Comment: No, build a multi-column combobox that displays name but saves ID. This is common technique https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762395/ms-access-display-two-columns-in-combo-box

Comment: I don't build lookups in tables, I build comboboxes on form. If you really must work with tables directly instead of forms, table lookup field should also be set up as multi-column to display name but save ID.

Comment: After your comment I was able to build multi-column combobox on tables, and it's exactly what my original intention was.  I will look more into building combobox on forms. Thank you very much.